# How to remove polygon under other one?

Tags: qgis, postgis, polygon

[image: http://bildr.no/image/1172970.jpeg]

Let's say that green polygon is under red and part of blue with yellow stripes is also under red polygon. How can I make one polygon from every polygons that intersects my main ( red ) polygon and also remove polygons ( all green and part of blue with yellow stripes ) under red polygon?

I'm using QuantumGIS and PostGIS.

I did this (in QGIS):

1. dissolve
2. multipart to singleparts

Please tell me that I'm right ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's the way. The only thing you have to take care is choosing the correct dissolve field (or avoid using it).

You can also try the [Sextante plugin](http://www.sextantegis.com/downloads.html). It includes another three dissolve tools, from SAGA, GRASS and fTools. But it's experimental right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ST_Intersects()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) in PostGIS,

> ST_Intersects — Returns TRUE if the Geometries/Geography "spatially intersect in 2D" - (share any portion of space) and FALSE if they don't (they are Disjoint). For geography -- tolerance is 0.00001 meters (so any points that close are considered to intersect)

This will show you all the Polygons that touch the red.

```
SELECT ST_Union(geom) WHERE ST_Intersects( 2ndpoly, geom );
```